# Blank RSS feed? But source viewable

Tags: xml, rss

I'm having trouble figuring out why the RSS feed appears blank for one page but not another.

Both have similar content, but for one the feed doesn't show up, but the source is viewable.

Working: http://craze.cc/popular/rss

Not working: http://craze.cc/new/rss

I tried using a validator, still confused on what is going on.

Help please! Also, I might not be at the computer for a day or so. So don't get mad if I don't choose a correct answer right away.

Comment: Are you generating the XML, or is a plugin/library/sometime else generating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second feed has at least one error. Here’s the helpful message Google Chrome gives:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 23 at column 131: Entity 'Acirc' not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `&#194;` using this should work.